# Javascript - Onmiddleclick on a div

Tags: javascript, onclick

i need a non Jquery middleclick solution for all new browser.
My idea was to use the onmiddleclick ... but this code does not work.

Hope someone can help.

**HTML / JS Code**

```
<div id="test" onmiddleclick="alert('middle');" ondblclick="alert('dbl');" > 
 CLICK HERE 
</div>
```

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/392BK/

Thanks in advance!

 Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function whichButton(e) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        switch (e.which) {
            case 1: alert("Left"); break;
            case 2: alert("Middle"); break;
            case 3: alert("Right"); break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test" onmouseup="whichButton()">Click Me</div>
```

Have a read of [this QuirksMode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button) for more information on event properties.

If possible, it's definitely worth using jQuery for things like this.  Cross-browser compatibility for mouse-clicks is poor, and you'll need something more like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/392BK/4/) to provide support in all browers.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, it's a bit of a nightmare really.  Browsers handle `which` and `button` differently, so you'll need to code around them (see the [QuirksMode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)).  Is there a reason you can't use jQuery? Much as I berated @netbrain's answer, jQuery really comes into its own when dealing with cross-browser inconsistencies like this.

Comment: @Peter: Without jQuery, you'll be looking at something a little more messy, like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/392BK/4/).

Answer (score 1):

There is updated code from "Town"
It will fix error in Firefox and prbably others browsers with "e is undefined" message.

In HTML you have to send event parameter like this:

`<div id="test" onmouseup="whichButton(event)">Click Me</div>`

Hope it will help you!

Comment: That won't work in IE as IE uses `event.button` instead of `event.which`.  See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

http://jsfiddle.net/392BK/1/

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#test").mousedown(function(b){
      if(b.which==1)alert('Left Mouse Button Clicked');
      else if(b.which==2)alert('Middle Mouse Button Clicked');
      else if(b.which==3)alert('Right Mouse Button Clicked');
    });
})
```

EDIT:

My bad, but the event types still applies.

Comment: Not to perpetuate the off-topicness too much, but `$().ready()` isn't recommended according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), although it's not specific as to why! If you want shorthand, I'd use `$(handler)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `onclick` and detecting clicks would be a good alternative.

Check [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onmousedown` event. The event object has a `button` property which contains a bitmask for the buttons pressed. The value 4 means that only the middle button is pressed.

Comment: [Only in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button).  Otherwise it's `1` for middle-click.